# In Amityville: The Awakening, what was wrong with James?

Tags: horror, amityville

Why was his body always turned to the side when he was lying in the bed?

Answer (score 1):

James suffered a traumatic injury after falling off of a balcony during a fight with "some guy" who'd posted intimate pictures of Bella online without her permission.

> **Bella:** *I sent these pictures to some guy. And then when I woke up the
>   next morning, they were all over the internet. They were everywhere,
>   everyone had seen them. Everyone at school and my Mom and my
>   brother...*
>
> **Maxine:** *So, what happened?*
>
> **Bella:** *James wanted to find the guy who did it, and he lived in a three-storey apartment building. **There was a really big fight and ....
>   he*** [James] ***went over the balcony.***

The ending suggests that he wasn't just comatose, he was in a [persistently vegetative state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_vegetative_state).

> **VO:** *But two years prior to the murders, James was in a coma, **a vegetative state.***

Answer (score 0):

He had a fight with the guy who cyber-bullied his sister Belle in a 3rd story apartment and fell of the balcony.
Belle herself explains this to her friend Marissa.